# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined

Tags: typescript, webpack

We are building a new console using TypeScript with the following dependencies (among others):

```
NodeJS-react = 16.2.x;
NodeJS-react-dom = 16.2.x;
NodeJS-react-intl = 2.4.x;
NodeJS-react-intl-redux = 0.6.x;
NodeJS-react-redux = 5.0.x;
NodeJS-types-react = 16.0.x;
NodeJS-types-react-dom = 16.0.x;
NodeJS-types-react-hot-loader = 3.0.x;
NodeJS-types-react-redux = 5.0.x;
NodeJS-types-react-intl = 2.3.x;
NodeJS-types-react-intl-redux = 0.1.x;
NodeJS-webpack = 3.9.x;
NodeJS-webpack-dev-server = 2.11.x;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined
at Object.__webpack_exports__.a (main.js:39995)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:84576)
at Object.REACT_STATICS.childContextTypes (main.js:84646)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
at Object.CLEARED (main.js:39878)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:67289)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:59465)
```

which points to this:

```
/* harmony default export */ 
__webpack_exports__["a"] = (__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["PropTypes"].shape({
```

Does anyone have a clue how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you check what React component is throwing this error?

Comment: from what I see in  the output main.js, the error is thrown when read-redux is trying to load